# How to fit an image without deforming his resolution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I need to fit a vertical image in a horizontal frame without deforming the image and filling the rest with white.Im using paperclip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's not a rails question, but a style (css) matter. Try to put some css like:

```
.img-paperclip{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

and, in your html element, something like:

```
<img src="..." class="img-paperclip" ...>
```

Hope it helps.